# I do not understand PHP references code that combines & and []

Tags: php, reference

I am reading some code in a library we use (SimplePie) and I am trying to find some memory issues.I found a code that is looking like the below and I do not understand what it does

```
<?php
$a1=array('a1first',2,3);
$a3=array();
$a3[]=&$a1;
var_dump($a1);
$a1=& $a1[];
var_dump($a1);
$a1="bbb";
echo "<br />";
var_dump($a1);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($a3);
?>
```

The output is

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "a1first" [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) } NULL 
string(3) "bbb" 
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "a1first" [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> &string(3) "bbb" } }
```

My question is what this line does and when to use it

```
$a1=& $a1[];
```

Comment: `&` gives you a reference rather than a copy of the value .. I have no idea what `&$a1[]` would be since `$a1[]` should be used as left-hand side in an assignment. I guess it just becomes `null` as you can see in your output.

Comment: First off, use some spacing, otherwise readability will also impair understandability.  It just creates a new empty array elements, and replaces the array root with a pointy references to the new empty element. "When to use it" is not generalizable.

Comment: @arc: that's not a bitwise "and" in OP's code. `&=` would be a bitwise asignment operation. `= &` is "assign a reference".

Comment: @MarcB Ah, I see. Thanks. I removed the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=&` returns a reference to the right hand side, rather than copying it.

`$a1` is an array, and `$a1[]` refers to the next empty position in the array, so you can say:

```
$a1[] = 4;
```

and 4 will be added to the existing array `$a1`.

I'm not sure if using `[]` on the right side of an assignment is valid, but what the code

```
$a1=& $a1[];
```

Is doing is saying `$a1` is now a pointer (reference) to the new value at the end of `$a1`. Obviously this is a bit circular, so I'm not sure what the point is!

Comment: can you find a documentation link that describes this? because without the & the syntax is not valid, so it may be something like pointer aritmetic maybe

Answer (score 2):

**`$a1=& $a1[];`** appends a new empty item in the array `$a1` (being itself a reference to `$a3`), and `$a1` is then set to be a reference to this item.